How to uninstall Astah UML?
I use Ubuntu 23.10. I'm trying to update the system, and it gives me this error message.

The astah-uml package needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

I do not remember when I tried to install it, but I already deleted the referring files and yet, the system keeps on outputting the same error message.

Please translate and ask the question in English

I'm trying to update my system, and there's a error when i try it. Like, last week i have tried to install Astah UML, and that not worked well, so id give up. Now, the archives reaming of astah are avoiding the update and upgrade for new ubuntu's version.

Please post the output of sudo apt update by editing the question. Also, when do you see the message The Astah Uml package needs to be reinstalled, but it was not possible to find a file for it.? Can you post the command you entered and the full error emssage?

I managed to solve it, but I believe I installed it wrongly, I used the command ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/info | grep -i astah and them it was deleted completely. I no longer have the screenshot with the terminal, but the command worked.
